# Can't initialize variables in for loop in C in VSCODE

Tags: c, compiler-errors, visual-studio-code

I think something wrong with my VSCode, since i can't initialize varibles in loops in C
For instance:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(){
     for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      printf("%i", i);
     }
     }
```

It gives compile error
How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Show the full error message.

Comment: coding.c: In function 'main':
coding.c:4:5: error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
coding.c:4:5: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code

Comment: What does prevent you to use the specified options?

Answer (score 1):

either declare i prior to the for loop or compile with "-std=c99"

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    printf("%i", i);
    }
 }
```